# Fetching data in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component in a redux app that needs to fetch data from a remote server.

Where is the proper place to make the call and handle all of its logic? action creator? smart component in a lifecycle method like componentDidMount?

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is the correct place to make an API call. Sometimes you might want it in `componentWillMount` depending on how early you want the data.

I would also recommend looking into redux-thunk which can help with creating actions that fetch data.

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your situation.

If you are building application using `smart / dumb` components concept, the best place, in my opinion, to perform api calls - is `componentDidMount` lifecycle callback:

```js
// SomeComponent.js

// ... other methods ...

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    todos: [],
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  // `axios` is ajax library
  axios.get('/todos')
    .then(todos => {
      this.setState({
        todos: todos
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

> Fetch data in componentDidMount. When the response arrives, store the data in state, triggering a render to update your UI.